# Creating internal compute cloud using Virtualbox/VMware

Tags: cloud, virtualbox, vmware, virtualization

I was wondering if we can create a personal Compute cloud server "in-premise" like EC2 in AWS or Compute Engine in GCP using VirtualBox or VMware.
The following scenario will help you understand.

- I have a desktop with 32GB Memory, 8 CPUs, static IP, etc.
- I want to use it as a central server to manage my virtual machine instances.
- The instances created on the central server need not be public.
- I will first SSH to the central server and then SSH to the instance.
- An interface on a central server to manage all instances.
- The process could be as easy as launching an EC2 instance.
- I should get the IP address of the instance in the interface itself.
- Should be Host-Guest (VMware, vbox, etc.) based instead of bare metal virtualization (xen, etc.).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this hardware configuration to host Open Stack basics services. Just install a hypervisor and start creating VMs. Many on-promise cloud use 64GB ram and more CPUs for Core Services (compute, control plane, network, storage) so if you plan to create VMs on Top of your VMs is possible to overkill memory and CPU.

Check open stack docs for start, good luck!
https://docs.openstack.org/victoria/?_ga=2.36072992.104053192.1614023389-2138807046.1614023389